ubuntu 24.04 HDMI not detected
I have been struggling for a week,
Searched the web and tried everything I found but nothing has worked.
System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-09-20 11:50:37

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Dell Inc. XPS 15 9520
Memory:                                      32.0 GiB
Processor:                                   12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-12700H × 20
Graphics:                                    Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)
Graphics 1:                                  NV177
Disk Capacity:                               (null)

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            1.26.0
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-45-generic

The HDMI is on Intel Grapics card
xrandr
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

did you try this: https://linuxcommunity.io/t/my-ubuntu-system-isnt-recognising-my-hdmi-connected-monitor-help/3416/7 ?
